# Shouldn't the ClickOnce Bootstrapper be included into Windows SDK?

Tags: .net, sdk, msbuild, clickonce, visual-studio-2012

I've installed Windows SDK for Windows 8, which contains Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 SDK.

I hoped to build my VS2012 project using MSBuild tool on the server.

But still, the ClickOnce application doesn't compile, nor I can find any setup.bin dependency to build ClickOnce setup file.

What should I install onto the build server to make it compile .NET 4.5 applications?

Comment: What is the error you get when you try and compile?

Comment: That it cannot find the Setup.bin

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically about 2012 and the issues with the SDK but you can manually control the source files of the bootstrapper build process by editing the registry, thereby bypassing the SDK.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\{Version}
```

Should contain a PATH setting. By changing this setting you can redirect where MSBuild picks up the packages for use with the Bootstrapper build process.

You should be able to set this setting somewhere and just copy your packages in there from a development machine. MSBuild should be part of the framework so if you are not actually building anything then you need to look at that.

Top tip if you are not sure is to go and have a look at how a Dev machine with VS on it works and just copy that on the server.